# Counting equal elements in a data.frame and plotting

Tags: r, dataframe, rmysql

I am using RMySQL to retrieve a table from the server. The result has columns

```
id
CountryCode
date
Value
```

`CountryCode` can repeat itself n times.

What I would like to do is to get the total count of all `CountryCode`s and then plot the result.

I am new to R so I am not sure if this is done with a `for` or there is a simpler way to go through the data.frame to get this information.

I appreciate any tip in the right direction
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are in a dataframe named "dfrm":

```
ctbl <- table(dfrm$CountryCode)
plot(ctble)
```